# Predicting the products of a redox reaction

Tags: redox

How can you predict how a given reactant will be reduced/oxidized? How can you predict how a given reactant will be reduced/oxidized? I would like to be able to do this without being given an electrochemical series chart. How can I then complete the half reaction?

Comment: In effect, you are asking how to predict the products of an unknown reaction, given the reactants. This question is as wide as chemistry itself.

Comment: then can u suggest me a book or give me a reference link

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/oxidation-reduction